# RegExp: currency format

Tags: regex

I need to format numbers so that thousands were not separated by anything and hundreds were separated with a dot. For example

1234.56
12.34
123

I wrote the following ReqExp

```
amountValue.replace(/^(\d+)[,.](\d{3})[.,](\d{2})$/,'$1' + '$2' +'.'+'$3').replace(/^(\d+),(\d{2})$/,'$1' +'.'+'$2');
```

If there a way to make it shorter?

Thank you!

Comment: As regexes go that is pretty short.

Comment: (Just look at the regex that matches email addresses if you don't believe that.)

Comment: A regex anyone could be proud of.

Comment: thank you :) I really thought it doesn't look good. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just remove any non numeric character that’s not the decimal point:

```
amountValue.replace(/[^0-9](?!\d{2}$)/, '').replace(/,(?=\d{2}$)/, '.');
```

Comment: This won't work in international (European) formats - the decimal is the thousand separator and the comma is the decimal separator.

Comment: Have you tested it? It works fine for me with values like "123.456,78", "123,456.78", "123,45" or "123.45"

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this might work:

```
amountValue.replace(/^(\d*)[,.]?(\d{0,3})[.,](\d{2})$/,'$1' + '$2' +'.'+'$3');
```

Try it against your data.